# How to get selected input Label value from radio group in extjs

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1, sencha-architect, extjs4.2

Can anybody tell me how to get the selected input Label value from a radio group in extjs? I have placed radio group in a form. I need to get the selected input Label value in controller in onChangemethod

```
onChangeAspectsradio: function (radioField, newVal, oldVal, eOpts){         
      console.log("new value is"+newVal); //here am getting object only             
},
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

try `newVal.individual`.

```
onChangeAspectsradio: function (radioField, newVal, oldVal, eOpts){
      console.log("new value is"+newVal.individual); 
},
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Ext.ComponentQuery.query('[name=test]')[0].getGroupValue();

{
    xtype          : 'radiofield',
    name           : 'test',
    inputValue     : '30',
    hideEmptyLabel : false,
    boxLabel       : 'testBox'
}
```

try this, should help. Remember setting `inputValue` property of radio

Comment: not working. `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'getGroupValue' `